# Returning relevant date from multiple tables including additional table info

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join

This is continuing on from a query that was solved previously via stackoverflow ([Returning nearest date to date in a different table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433465/returning-nearest-date-to-date-in-a-different-table-oracle)), however, I now wish to develop it a little further.

The SQL I have is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID as "P Number", 
             O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID as "Assessment ID", 
             O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE as "Assessment Start",  
             O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE as "Assessment End", 
             O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_ID as "Event ID", 
             O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE as "Event Start", 
             O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_OUTCOME_DATE as "Event End",
             ROUND(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE -O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE,0) as "Likely",
             row_number() over(PARTITION BY  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID                                    
                               ORDER BY abs(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE -  O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE))as "Row Number"            
      FROM O_ASSESSMENTS 
      JOIN O_SERVICE_EVENTS
        ON O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID = O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_SUBJECT_ID
      Where O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_CODE IN ('ICS_E3','CPINVEST') AND 
            O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_QSA_ID  IN ('AA1329','AA521') )
WHERE "Row Number" = 1
```

Basically, we have two tables - o_assessments and o_service_events, and this SQL is returning the nearest service event to the assessment.  Now I want to include some more contexual information into the query to make it more helpful for the end user - namely the team name and the worker name.

Unfortunately, team and worker are in a different table again (o_responsibilities), and are linked to the o_assessments by asm_id to res_rec_id.

Problem is, I'm really not sure how to call this table into the above sql - so any advice would really be appreciated!

I was also wondering if it would be possible to tweak the existing query to only return corresponding events when the 'likely' field had a difference of 0 (as anything greater is probably not related to that particular assessment).  I know I can add it into the where, but if I add the line

```
and "Likely" = 0
```

it only returns assessments with an event, which wouldn't highlight any issues (i.e. assessments without corresponding events).

I'm learning all the time with SQL, but there are a lot of things that just seem really beyond me at the moment, so any advice is much appreciated!  I wasn't sure whether to amend my original query or to start a new one, so I hope I haven't infringed on any rules inadvertently.

Edit:

Okay, following Mark's solution, this is what I have working.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
(SELECT 
OAS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID as "P Number",
OAS.ASM_ID as "Assessment ID",
OAS.ASM_START_DATE as "Assessment Start", 
OAS.ASM_END_DATE as "Assessment End",
OAS.ASM_AUTH_DATETIME as "Authorisation Date",
nvl(olm_bo.get_ref_desc(OAS.ASM_OUTCOME,'ASM_OUTCOME'),'') as "Outcome",
nvl(olm_bo.get_org_name(ORE.RES_PARTY_OUN_ID),'') as "Team",
nvl(olm_bo.get_per_name(ORE.RES_PARTY_ID),'') as "Worker",
OSE.SEV_ID as "Event ID",
OSE.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE as "Event Start",
OSE.SEV_OUTCOME_DATE as "Event End",
ROUND(OAS.ASM_START_DATE -OSE.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE,0) as "Likely",
row_number() over(PARTITION BY  OAS.ASM_ID                   
ORDER BY 
abs(OAS.ASM_START_DATE -  OSE.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE))as "Row Number"
FROM O_ASSESSMENTS OAS      
INNER JOIN O_RESPONSIBILITIES ORE ON OAS.ASM_ID = ORE.RES_REC_ID
AND ORE.RES_PARTY_OUN_ID = 'TEAM'
LEFT JOIN O_SERVICE_EVENTS OSE ON OAS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID = OSE.SEV_SUBJECT_ID 
AND            
OSE.SEV_CODE IN ('EVENT') 
AND             
ROUND(OAS.ASM_START_DATE - OSE.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE,0) >= -7
AND
ROUND(OAS.ASM_START_DATE - OSE.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE,0) <= 7
Where OAS.ASM_QSA_ID  IN ('ACODE')
AND
nvl(olm_bo.get_ref_desc(OAS.ASM_OUTCOME,'ASM_OUTCOME'),'') <> 'Abandon' ) WHERE "Row Number" = 1
```

Comment: is something missing from the inner select? Specifically around the join... it has an "AND" followed by a "WHERE" which should result in a SYNTAX error

Comment: Sorry, was fiddling with the code and copied the wrong copy across...fixed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT OAS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID as "P Number", 
             OAS.ASM_ID as "Assessment ID", 
             OAS.ASM_START_DATE as "Assessment Start",  
             OAS.ASM_END_DATE as "Assessment End", 
             ORE.TEAM,
             ORE.WORKER,
             OSE.SEV_ID as "Event ID", 
             OSE.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE as "Event Start", 
             OSE.SEV_OUTCOME_DATE as "Event End",
             ROUND(OAS.ASM_START_DATE -OSE.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE,0) as "Likely",
             row_number() over(PARTITION BY  OAS.ASM_ID                                    
                               ORDER BY abs(OAS.ASM_START_DATE -  OSE.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE))as "Row Number"            
      FROM O_ASSESSMENTS OAS
      LEFT JOIN O_RESPONSIBILITIES ORE
        ON OAS.ASM_ID = ORE.RES_REC_ID
      LEFT JOIN O_SERVICE_EVENTS OSE
        ON OAS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID = OSE.SEV_SUBJECT_ID AND
           OSE.SEV_CODE IN ('ICS_E3','CPINVEST') AND 
           ROUND(OAS.ASM_START_DATE - OSE.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE,0) = 0
      Where OAS.ASM_QSA_ID  IN ('AA1329','AA521') )
WHERE "Row Number" = 1
```

Note that this assumes that RES_REC_ID is a unique identifier on O_RESPONSIBILITIES.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this appears to be working perfectly.  Apologies for the delay on the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a new one is the right course of action; editing a question to "add scope" is not a good practice.  This falls into "Adding scope" so a new question was the correct approach.

```
SELECT
ID, "Assessment ID", 
"Assessment Start", "Assessment End", "Event ID", 
"Event Start", "Event End", Likely, Team_name, Worker_name
FROM
  (SELECT 
  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID as "ID", 
  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID as "Assessment ID", 
  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE as "Assessment Start",  
  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE as "Assessment End", 
  O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_ID as "Event ID", 
  O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE as "Event Start", 
  O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_OUTCOME_DATE as "Event End",
  ROUND(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE -O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE,0) as "Likely",
  row_number() over(PARTITION BY  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID                                    
    ORDER BY abs(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE -  
    O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_ACTUAL_DATE))    as "Row    Number",
  RES.TEAM_NAME,
  RES.WORKER_NAME
  FROM O_ASSESSMENTS 
  INNER JOIN  O_SERVICE_EVENTS
    ON O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID = O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_SUBJECT_ID
  INNER JOIN O_Responsibilities res 
    ON O_Assessments.ASM_ID = res.res_rec_ID
  WHERE O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_CODE IN ('ICS_E3','CPINVEST')
    AND O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_QSA_ID IN ('AA1329','AA521') )  InnerTable
WHERE "Row Number" = 1 and (Likely = 0 or LIKELY is null)
```

All I did here was

1. Add your Join criteria on the inner select statement
2. Included the columns you asked for, though the names were not provided so I assumed TEAM_NAME and WORKER_NAME, on the INNER and OUTER select statements
3. Eliminated the AND after the join before the where as in comment to original post
4. Added an alias to table name in inner select incase joins are needed
   to outer table at some point.
5. Added the (likely = 0   or likely is null) to outer where clause
6. Reformatted SQL a bit to keep readable here.

per 5 above, it may not quite be correct, I don't fully understand your comment about assessments not having service dates.  If that is the case, the Join between assessments and services MUST be a left join, instead of an INNER, if you want ALL assessments and related services if they exist.  Currently you are getting only those assessments which HAVE related services. IF you need all assessments other changes may be required.

So...

```
  FROM O_ASSESSMENTS 
  INNER JOIN  O_SERVICE_EVENTS
    ON O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID = O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_SUBJECT_ID
```

would become (only INNER to LEFT was changed)

```
  FROM O_ASSESSMENTS 
  LEFT JOIN  O_SERVICE_EVENTS
    ON O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID = O_SERVICE_EVENTS.SEV_SUBJECT_ID
```

and it assumes assessment always has a responsibilities record, if not a LEFT join would be needed there as well.

Lastly, thought would need to be given as to what result you wnat for LIKELY when the SEV_Actual_Date is null.  What value should likely have?

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately just finishing for the year, so might not have a chance to test it before January, but will certainly have a look - thank you especially for explaining what you have done, as this is the kind of help I need!

Comment: @xQbert - This won't return assessments where likely is neither 0 nor null.

Comment: I'm missing something... (Likely=0 or Likely is null) should do it.  However the INNER join currently prevents a NULL value and I indicated as such in my response; as I did not fully understand OPs requirement.

Comment: The point of the selection by row number is that the OP wants the first-ranked service event by closest date - there could be multiple events with a matching subject ID, but only one where the dates match is likely to be a true match of event to assessment. (Likely=0 or Likely is null) will return assessments with service events on the same day (Likely=0) or assessments without any matching service events by subject (Likely is null, when left joining to service events). It will not return assessments where the first matching event is not on the same day, which the OP wants to highlight.

Comment: Thanks both for your response, MB was correct in saying I wanted to return assessments with their most likely corresponding event, though not all assessments would necessarily have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can just join `o_responsibilities` to your inline view on the respective IDs and then include its columns in the query.

Be aware that you would need to put the `where likely = 0` bit in the outer query (with the row number criterion), rather than the inline view, because `likely` is an alias. If you want to highlight assessments without events, then you should do a `left join` and also add the condition that the `sev_id is null`.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select  *
from   (select    o_assessments.asm_subject_id                      as "P Number", 
                  o_assessments.asm_id                              as "Assessment ID", 
                  o_assessments.asm_start_date                      as "Assessment Start",  
                  o_assessments.asm_end_date                        as "Assessment End", 
                  o_service_events.sev_id                           as "Event Id", 
                  o_service_events.sev_actual_date                  as "Event Start", 
                  o_service_events.sev_outcome_date                 as "Event End",
                  o_responsibilities.[WHATEVER]                     as "Team/Worker Stuff",
                  round(o_assessments.asm_start_date - o_service_events.sev_actual_date,0)
                                                                    as "Likely",
                  row_number() over (partition by o_assessments.asm_id                                    
                                     order by     abs(o_assessments.asm_start_date - o_service_events.sev_actual_date))
                                                                    as rn
        from      o_assessments 
        left join o_service_events
        on        o_service_events.sev_subject_id                    = o_assessments.asm_subject_id
        left join o_responsibilities
        on        o_responsibilities.res_rec_id                      = o_assessments.asm_id
        where     o_service_events.sev_code                         in ('ICS_E3','CPINVEST')
        and       o_assessments.asm_qsa_id                          in ('AA1329','AA521'))
where   rn = 1
and    (likely = 0 or sev_id is null);
```

Comment: This won't return assessments where likely is neither 0 nor null.

Comment: No, the OP didn't. See my comment on xQbert's answer for further clarification.

Comment: Fair enough; then change to `and (likely != 0 or sev_id is null);`

Comment: Still won't work, as then it wouldn't return assessments that *do* have matching service events.

Comment: I'm possibly missing something here -- it is a slow day, after all! -- but in that case, isn't the extra `where` clause on `likely` irrelevant as it would set up a tautology? `p∨¬p` is always true in binary logic; the only other thing to account for would be the `null` service events.

Comment: I did, but like I say, I'm obviously missing something :P